# How to drop all columns but not first that starts with pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have code that deletes all columns that are starting with `spike`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'spike_starts1': [1,2,3], 'spike_starts2': [4,5,6], 'spike_starts3': [7,8,9], 'not': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = '^spike')].tolist() , axis=1).copy()
```

**Question:** How to modify code above so that it will leave first column that starts with `spike` but delete all others that starts with `spike`? If code above is hard to modify suggest your own versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved just by changing `.tolist()[1:]`, the final code must look like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'spike_starts1': [1,2,3], 'spike_starts2': [4,5,6], 'spike_starts3': [7,8,9], 'not': [10,11,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = '^spike')].tolist()[1:] , axis=1).copy()
```

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you are deleting first value of the list that is created by `df.columns.str.contains(pat = '^spike')].tolist()` before passing it to `.drop()` ?

Comment: @vasili111 You're right, I'm not literally deleting it, because it will still exist in the list, but I will skip the `list[0]` position by using `list[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a spike flag and drop duplicates which will only keep the first one.

```
(
    df.T.assign(flag=lambda x: x.index.str.slice(0,5))
    .drop_duplicates(subset='flag')
    .drop('flag',1)
    .T
)

    spike_starts1   not
0   1               10
1   2               11
2   3               12
```

Of you can build a dict with only the first spike column and other non spike columns.

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'spike' if c.startswith('spike') else c:df[c] for c in df.columns})
    .rename(columns = {'spike': [e for e in df.columns if e.startswith('spike')][0]})
)
```

Another solution:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(df.columns)
    .assign(F=lambda x: x[0].str[:5])
    .drop_duplicates(subset='F')
    .pipe(lambda x: df.reindex(columns=x[0]))
)
```